# Merge two tables on two columns without order of variables playing a role

Tags: r, merge

I have two tables with different row numbers. I would like to merge the tables based on the content of two columns. However, the catch is I don't want the order of the variables to matter when merging. Example:

### Table1:

```
Gene1 Gene2   p-value
TP53  ARID1A  0.001
ATM   ATR     0.0005
```

### Table2:

```
Gene1  Gene2  p-value
ARID1A  TP53  0.0007
ATM     ATR   0.004
```

I tried:

```
merge(Table1, Table2, by = c("Gene1", "Gene2"), all.x = TRUE)
```

But the problem is that it will only merge 'ATM' and 'ATR' but not 'TP53' and 'ARID1A' because they are not in the same order.

Is there a way to merge the two tables irrespective of the column order?

Comment: You could try `merge(t1,t2,by=c("Gene1","Gene2"),all=TRUE)`.

Comment: This would partially work. Now I get a large table of both tables. However, 'TP53' 'ARID1A' and 'ARID1A' 'TP53' appear as separate rows. I was wondering whether there was a way they would appear on the same row.

Comment: Please share your expected output so it would be simpler for us to figure out the solution.

Comment: Sort the gene names then merge, so that we are sure that "TP53, ARID1A" couple will always have "ARID1A" on the Gene1 column.

Comment: @Chirayu Chamoli I would like the output to be: `TP53  ARID1A  0.001  0.0007` for the first row and of course `ATM  ATR  0.0005  0.004` for the second row. So basically, that the rows will be merged when the combination of Gene1 and Gene2 are shared between the two tables but not necessary in that order. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("
SELECT df1.*, 
       df2.`p.value` 
FROM   df1, df2 
WHERE (df1.Gene1 = df2.Gene1 AND
       df1.Gene2 = df2.Gene2) OR
      (df1.Gene1 = df2.Gene2 AND
       df1.Gene2 = df2.Gene1)")

#   Gene1  Gene2 p.value p.value
# 1  TP53 ARID1A   1e-03   7e-04
# 2   ATM    ATR   5e-04   4e-03
```

Comment: Some of "or" must be "and".

Comment: Yeah middle one should be and.

Comment: We might also need some "()".

Comment: tks for that. i am running late for home, that would be the reason for being sloppy.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in standard pandas?

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio later i will check this.

Answer (score 1):

We can sort gene names then merge:

```
#sort gene names
df1$GeneMin <- pmin(df1$Gene1, df1$Gene2)
df1$GeneMax <- pmax(df1$Gene1, df1$Gene2)

df2$GeneMin <- pmin(df2$Gene1, df2$Gene2)
df2$GeneMax <- pmax(df2$Gene1, df2$Gene2)

# then merge
merge(df1, df2, by = c("GeneMin", "GeneMax"))
#   GeneMin GeneMax Gene1.x Gene2.x p.value.x Gene1.y Gene2.y p.value.y
# 1  ARID1A    TP53    TP53  ARID1A     1e-03  ARID1A    TP53     7e-04
# 2     ATM     ATR     ATM     ATR     5e-04     ATM     ATR     4e-03

# tidy up columns, column names
#....
```

Or we can merge twice then rbind:

```
# double merge, this might cause unexpected results
rbind(
  merge(df1, df2, by = c("Gene1", "Gene2")),
  merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("Gene1", "Gene2"), by.y = c("Gene2", "Gene1"))
  )
#   Gene1  Gene2 p.value.x p.value.y
# 1   ATM    ATR     5e-04     4e-03
# 2  TP53 ARID1A     1e-03     7e-04
```

**Data**

```
# data
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Gene1 Gene2   p-value
TP53  ARID1A  0.001
ATM   ATR     0.0005", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
Gene1  Gene2  p-value
ARID1A  TP53  0.0007
ATM     ATR   0.004", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```